# Force SymPy symbols to not commute with matrices

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, symbols, commutativity

I'm using SymPy to solve a linear system of equations of matrices. However, I'm not using SymPy's MatrixSymbol object because it doesn't seem to play nice with `solve_linear_system`. So instead I'm just using normal symbols with `commutative=False`, which seems to work fine.

However, when I try to finally substitute in the matrices to evaluate the solution, I run into the problem that **non-commutative SymPy symbols are still permitted to commute with SymPy matrices**. For example:

```
import sympy as sy

A, B = sy.symbols('A, B', commutative=False)
expr = A*B

print(expr.subs(A, sy.eye(2)))
print(expr.subs(B, sy.eye(2)))
```

gives

```
Matrix([
[1, 0],
[0, 1]])*B
Matrix([
[1, 0],
[0, 1]])*A
```

This results in incorrect matrix multiplication order when substituting in multiple values:

```
X = sy.Matrix([[1,1],[0,0]])
Y = sy.Matrix([[0,1],[0,1]])

print(expr.subs({A: X, B: Y}))
print(X*Y)
```

gives

```
Matrix([[0, 0], [0, 0]])
Matrix([[0, 2], [0, 0]])
```

Is there some way to avoid symbols commuting with matrices during the substitution process? Using `simultaneous=True` on the `subs` call doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all symbols need to be non-commutative for SymPy to respect non-commutativity. So if I define one commutative symbol and one non-commutative symbol then SymPy will assume that they commute:

```
In [15]: A = Symbol('A', commutative=False)                                                                                                                   

In [16]: B = Symbol('B', commutative=True)                                                                                                                    

In [17]: A*B                                                                                                                                                  
Out[17]: B⋅A

In [18]: A*B - B*A                                                                                                                                            
Out[18]: 0
```

I guess this means that when you substitute the commutative identity matrix SmyPy is happy to reorder the factors:

```
In [3]: ask(Q.commutative(eye(2)))                                                                                                                            
Out[3]: True
```

In general I'm not sure how well non-commutativity works in SymPy but I would have thought you'd be better with `MatrixSymbol`. Maybe it's easier to make that work with `solve_linear_system` than fix these problems...